# Building a dataset covering all possible combinations of class imbalances

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

As I'm trying to do a customized and dinamic plot of the ROC Curve and f1, I'm building a dataset upon such plot will be based. So, the plot needs to cover all possible ROC curves and f1. For this, we know that:

1. The roc curve is a function of the true positive rate and false positive rate.
2. The f1 score is a function of recall and precision.
3. Points (1) and (2) are a function of some combination of true positives (TP), true negatives (TN), false positives (FP), and/or false negatives (FN).

So, If I have a dataset that covers all possible combinations of TP, TN, FP, FN I could be able to plot every possible roc and f1 curve. This is what I have reached so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'TP': 0,
              'TN': 0,
              'FP': 100 - np.arange(0, 101,1),
              'FN': np.arange(0, 101,1)})
```

Putting a `np.arange()` to cover each "big combination" is pretty inefficient and I'm struggling to control possible mistakes.

For simplicity, you can assume that every combination has a total of 100 observations (`TP+TN+FP+FN= total observations`).

PS: The plot is thought to be dynamic, using plotly like [this](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/) one, where I would use the slide-bars to define what combination of TP, TN, FP, FN I would like to set in order to see the changes in the ROC and f1 curves.

Comment: I did curve_roc on pyqt5, where you can change the ratio of fpr and tpr with a slider. Here you can see how it works.[link](https://quant12345.github.io/) The question is, how will you receive ROC for TP + TN + FP + FN, do you have a model with your own settings for each combination?

Comment: It's not for a model, it's just for understanding how both curves moves given certain results (every results combination), and comparing those differences in order to see where a certain evaluation metric is not convenient. The reason why I'm using only 100 observations is because with 100 observations to have all the combinations would be 3.921.225 rows (a combination operation of 100 over 4, if maths doesn't fail me). Your plot will be a nice start anyways, I will give it a shot, thanks!